# Get the display property value of an element

Tags: javascript, css, dom

Using the sample below, I'm trying to get return the display value or trs[1].

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script>
    const trs = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    trs[1].style.display = "hidden";
    console.log(trs[1].style.getPropertyValue('display'));
</script>
```

I would expect the the result to be "hidden" for trs[1] and NULL or "" for trs[0]. However in the console, i'm not getting any property value back for either trs[0/1].

I'm not sure if i'm using the right method to return a css property value that is set dynamically in js.

Thanks
JR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value isn't set as "hidden" isn't a valid value. Try:

```
trs[1].style.display = "none";
console.log(trs[1].style.getPropertyValue('display'));
```

Comment: 2 hours I've been beating myself up as to why the above wasn't working. Thanks Adrian.

Comment: @Jaxchief - No worries